# Writing on top of an image

Tags: css, image, text

I have an image in my website, and I want to add an option to print it. So I've found a way to do it, but I want the words "Print Image" to be on top of the image, in it's left-bottom edge.

How do I add the sentence?

Thanks ahead.

[This is the image](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/4045/606h.jpg), the text in the left- bottom edge means "Print Image".

Comment: Have you tried to research this at all yourself? What have you tried? What problems have you bee having?

Comment: I've tried reseraching it for about an hour.. It seemed really easy to me at first. I know it seems a dumb question but I tried hard and still can't do it, plus I'm a beginner at this, so help me please...

Comment: So where did your research lead you?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read about absolute/relative positioning.

Comment: I was able to write on top of the image, but I couldn't bring the text to the bottom of it, only to the left side. So after trying many stuff that didn't work, I decided to write on the image in photoshop and cut it to 2 parts, add them separately as divs to my html and putting a link on the part with the text. After a lot of playing with it, it looked fine (the code is really long and unaesthetic though) but there still is a padding on the bottom that if I remove, gets the image up to where it can't be seen.

Comment: I read about absolute and relative, and it has problems with the margins and paddings, that's what happened in my above comment. This is the image: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/4045/606h.jpg. The text in the left-bottom edge means "Print Image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="image.gif" alt="preview" />
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; cursor:pointer" onclick="...">Print Image</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you want to create a text overlay that is positioned on the bottom left of the image. To achieve this objective you can wrap your text in a span inline element which is wrapped in a div with position set to absolute. Set the top and left property to meet your preference.
Sample code would look like this:

```
<div id="content">
<div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 100px;"> <!-- Change these parameters to reflect proper placement depending on the size of your image -->
<span>Print Image</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Of course you can implement the styling in a css file.
Hope this is useful.